# Term for"getting out of a business deal"

Tags: synonyms, business-language, legalese

Is there a legal/business term for "getting out of a [business] deal"?

The context is say somebody has done everything he/she was supposed to do, and handed over all his/her responsibilities to someone else. That person now wants to write or say something like "I'm done, I'm out of this deal/business/enterprise". Is there a better or more technical way to express that?

Comment: *Deal* is itself a rather vague term, and is definitely not a formal legal term, so one cannot expect there to be a legal term that would mean exactly 'getting out of a deal'. If one wishes to use a legal term for getting out of a particular deal, one first needs to know what the legal term for that particular deal is and what the legal nature of getting out of it is; if one knows that, the answer will be obvious

Comment: @jsw29 Not sure about the exact nature of said business deal, but let's assume for the sake of the argument, that it's a real estate transaction (e.g. purchase or sale of a house, or even a rental agreement).

Comment: Again, a lot would depend on what precisely the transaction itself is called, what stage of the transaction has been reached so far, what provisions have already been made about the possibility of pulling out, what consequences of pulling our one is willing to accept, what jurisdiction one is in, etc. Once all these details are filled in, the question would turn out into a legal question, rather than a question that can be answered on a site devoted to English language in general.

Comment: I am not after a *specific* answer but a *generic* one, that can apply to a wide variety of situations. The real estate one is just an example. The term doesn't *have* to be legal, it can be  simple "business speak".

Comment: I really think you need to provide more context. That said, if you want something really generic, you could probably say something like, "I am no longer involved in/participating in/ associated with this transaction."

Comment: @IsabelArcher, the formulations you suggest might be apt if the deal is not yet made and one is just pulling out of the negotiations, or after one has already completed the arrangements for undoing the deal. But if one is bound by a valid contract, one cannot just say that one is 'no longer involved'; the contract makes one involved.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a contractual obligation you are talking about, one may [void](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/void), [annul](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/annul), or [invalidate](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/invalidate) the contract.

Comment: One may void/annul/invalidate the contract only if it is legally possible to do so, and whether it is legally possible to do so depends on the specifics of the situation. One may also breach the contract (and accept the consequences) or try to renegotiate it. But perhaps, the contract hasn't yet been entered into, and one is only pulling out of the negotiations about it. We don't know the specifics, and if we did know them, it would still require **legal** expertise, specific to the jurisdiction, to answer the question.